Excel VBA splitting a string into a Date
I have a string that I want to split into the format MM/DD/YYYY. Example: "TIME_STAMP : Mon Jul 22 15:45:43 2024" will need to be split and the result should be "7/22/2024" if possible, but if just as a string "Jul 22 2024" works as well. Below is a code I found online, but can't seem to work.
Function ReturnNthElement(CellRef As Range, ElementNumber As Integer)
Dim Result() As String
Result = Split(CellRef, ",")
ReturnNthElement = Result(ElementNumber - 1)
End Function



You can use this method:
Dim TextTime As String
Dim TrueDate As Date

TextTime = "TIME_STAMP : Mon Jul 22 15:45:43 2024" 
TrueDate = DateValue(Right(TextTime, 4) & Mid(TextTime, 17, 7))


if you don't mind can you explain the meaning of DateValue(Right(TextTime, 4) & Mid(TextTime, 17, 7)) like how it works?

@user23357972 Right(TextTime, 4) = "2024", Mid(TextTime, 17, 7) = " Jul 22 15:45:43" so "2024" & " Jul 22 15:45:43" then DateValue("2024 Jul 22 15:45:43") is a syntax that vba recognises and can convert to a timestamp for you

Warning for the few non-US centric people around: This will fail to work if month names of the date string and month names of your local regional settings differ. On my computer, for example, I am using german date format. DateValue("2024 Jul 22 15:45:43") will work (as "Jul" is the same in german), but DateValue("2024 May 22 15:45:43") will fail (as "May" in german is "Mai")

The split function that you are using is trying to split your string by comma separated values. I.e. Result = Split(CellRef, ",")
As your string is not comma separated, it fails as cannot find a comma.
Use the inbuilt Replace function or Substitute function to replace the spaces in your cell with commas first and then that part of the  function should work.

Replace? - The default separator of the split function is a space (needs no delimiter argument at all - or " " instead of ",")

Good point - my bad
